# What is the proper term for this 'sliding navbar'?

Tags: mobile, interface, mobile-application

Many mobile apps implement this type of design.

These imgur screenshots show the sliding navbar for a youtube channel. Is there a proper name for this design?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern, as it appears here in the YouTube mobile app, is based on Google's Material Design language.

That navigation element is called a '**Tab Bar**'

And the scrolling version is called a '**Scrolling Tab Bar**'

See diagrams on this page for reference: https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html#tabs-usage

Comment: This is not a pattern based on Google's design language. It's older than that, and been used in other mediums (PCs, Web) long before smartphones.